# Django: end_time = models.TimeField. Is there a way to subtract minutes from this field?

Tags: django

I am trying to automatically subtract 60s or 1 minute from an end_time input by the user. Is there a way to do this? I am using Django v3.2.

model.py

end_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)

views.py

```
def post(self, request):
        booking_form = BookingForm(data=request.POST)
        if booking_form.is_valid():
            booking = booking_form.save(commit=False)
            booking.user = request.user
            if Booking.objects.filter(
                    table=booking.table, date=booking.date,
                    start_time=booking.start_time,
                    approved=booking.approved is True
                    ).exists():
                return render(request, '/',)
            else:
                booking.save()
            return render(request, '/',)
```

Comment: Last one minute?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. This is a restaurant booking service. Naturally, a User will book a table from Ex: 12pm to 13pm but if the next user wants to book the same table from 13pm to 14pm the function will not allow the booking due to overlap from previous booking end_time = new booking start_time being the same. As a solution if I can remove 1min from every booing end_time, this should allow new users to succeed with their booking... I hope this clarifies the problem statement further.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt # added here
def post(self, request):
        booking_form = BookingForm(data=request.POST)
        if booking_form.is_valid():
            booking = booking_form.save(commit=False)
            booking.user = request.user
            if Booking.objects.filter(
                    table=booking.table, date=booking.date,
                    start_time=booking.start_time,
                    end_time=booking.end_time - dt.timedelta(seconds=60), # modified here
                    approved=booking.approved is True
                    ).exists():
                return render(request, '/',)
            else:
                booking.save()
            return render(request, '/',)
```

Comment: I tried this before - Exception Value: 
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: You are confusing with the date time. datetime is a package which contains datetime module. You have to use datetime.timedelta, not datetime.datetime.timedelta.
Now,
import datetime as dt
use it like: dt.timedelta, modified the answer as you probably have datetime package already used somewhere.